# update listview in android as Adapter is defined in separate class

Tags: android, listview, adapter

As I have gone through number of questions to how can I refresh my listview in my app but still not able to get how to do it.

Number of suggestion given in Posts that I can use `mylist.NotifydataSetCahnged()` but I still couldn't able to resolve where to apply it. As my adapter is defined in the separate activity.

I have a textview and a plus button on each row of the List item.

On clicking plus button, I want it that without refreshing whole activity it asynchronously update the value in respective textview. And the plus button click event is declared in my baseadapter class separately.

I don't know how to update my listview as I'm calling intent on each click of plus button to refresh my listview.

Do help me out.

```
public class MyOrderList extends Activity {


    public Cursor food_items = null;
    private String item_name;
    private String item_descrp;
    private String item_price;
    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details;

    private String item_id;
    private Cursor order_item;
    private Button order_btn;
    private Button cancel_btn;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private AlertDialog mydialog;
    protected String table_no;
    protected String order_no;
    protected int quantity;
    protected int itemid;
    protected Cursor temp_item;
    public float Total = 0;
    private ListView lv1;
    public int bill_count = 100;
    private Cursor fav_item;
    private String table_name;
    private Calendar c;
    private TextView Title_txt;
    private String device_id;
    private String print_order_items = "";
    private String col_name;

    public static String APP_ID = "346381592110362"; // Replace your App ID

    public Facebook facebook;
    public AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private AlertDialog noItemalert;
    private Dialog checkOut;
    private Cursor mac;
    private String Main_table = "T1";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_myorder_view);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("restaurant", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
        c = Calendar.getInstance();

        // ----initilaizee facebook objects-
        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        SessionStore.restore(facebook, this);

        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
        SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
        table_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("table_name");
        // WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        // WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        // String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
        //
        // Log.d("IMEI no.", macAddress);
        // mac = db.rawQuery("select * from imei_tbl where imei_code='"
        // + macAddress + "'", null);
        // mac.moveToFirst();
        // if (mac != null)
        // Main_table = mac.getString(1);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myorder_lv);
        Title_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myorder_total);
        Title_txt.setText("Total :" + Total);

        order_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myorder_btn);
        cancel_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myorder_backbtn);

        cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyOrderList.this,
                        FoodCategoryTabs.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("category_id", "food_category");
                extras.putString("category_name", "food_category_id");
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        // ----------------on order click--------------
        order_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int flagx = 0;
                if (food_items.getCount() != 0)
                    showpopup();
                else
                    checkOutPopUp(flagx);

            }

        });

    }

    protected void showpopup() {
        final int flag = 1;

        mydialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("My Order Alert")
                .setMessage(
                        "Thank you Dear Customer, Your Order will processed soon Would you like to proceed further...")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        continueFunction();
                        checkOutPopUp(flag);
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Discard", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mydialog.dismiss();

                    }
                })

                .create();
        mydialog.show();
    }

    protected void checkOutPopUp(final int flag_value) {
        checkOut = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyOrderList.this)
                .setTitle("CheckOut Alert !")
                .setMessage(
                        "Would you like to continue to add items or checkout..")
                .setPositiveButton("Continue",
                        new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MyOrderList.this,
                                        FoodCategoryTabs.class);
                                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                                extras.putString("category_id", "food_category");
                                extras.putString("category_name",
                                        "food_category_id");
                                intent.putExtras(extras);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Checkout",
                        new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                if (flag_value != 0) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "checkout click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection(

                                    getApplicationContext());
                                    try {

                                        dbConnection.createSocket();
                                        dbConnection.dataOutputStream
                                                .writeUTF("3");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    }

                                    db.delete(table_name, "order_id=100", null);

                                    Cursor fav_cursor = db.rawQuery(
                                            "select * from temp_favourite_tbl",
                                            null);
                                    fav_cursor.moveToFirst();
                                    int length = fav_cursor.getCount();
                                    try {
                                        dbConnection.dataOutputStream
                                                .write(length);
                                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    if (fav_cursor != null) {
                                        do {
                                            try {
                                                String query = "insert into favourite_tbl values('";
                                                query = query
                                                        + fav_cursor
                                                                .getString(0)
                                                        + "','"
                                                        + fav_cursor
                                                                .getString(1)
                                                        + "')";
                                                dbConnection.dataOutputStream
                                                        .writeUTF(query);
                                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                            }

                                        } while (fav_cursor.moveToNext());
                                    }
                                    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_favourite_tbl");
                                    db.execSQL("create table if not exists temp_favourite_tbl(item_id varchar2,user_id varchar2,primary key(item_id))");
                                }
                                if (HeaderFooterActivity.facebook != null) {
                                    if (HeaderFooterActivity.facebook
                                            .isSessionValid()) {
                                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                        cv.put("login_txt", "Login");
                                        cv.put("username", "");
                                        cv.put("user_id", "");
                                        db.update("login_tbl", cv, null, null);

                                        HeaderFooterActivity.mAsyncRunner
                                                .logout(getApplicationContext(),
                                                        new LogoutRequestListener());

                                    }
                                } else {

                                    Log.d("logout me exeption", "");
                                }

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MyOrderList.this,
                                        GridViewMenu.class);

                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })

                .create();
        checkOut.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        table_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("table_name");
        getFoodItems(table_name);
        // calculateOrder();
        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myorder_lv);
        MyOrderAdapter ad = new MyOrderAdapter(this, image_details, table_name);
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv1.setAdapter(ad);
    }

    public void continueFunction() {
        try {
            Cursor customer_order = db.rawQuery(
                    "select bill_no from auto_bill", null);
            customer_order.moveToFirst();

            String bill_no = Main_table + customer_order.getCount();
            DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection(
                    getApplicationContext());
            dbConnection.createSocket();

            dbConnection.dataOutputStream.writeUTF("2");

            dbConnection.dataOutputStream
                    .writeUTF("insert into auto_bill(bill_no) values('"
                            + bill_no + "')");
            db.execSQL("insert into auto_bill(bill_no) values('" + bill_no
                    + "')");

            System.out.println("passed");

            dbConnection.dataOutputStream
                    .writeUTF("insert into CUSTOMER_BILL(table_no,bill_no,status,price,day,month,year) values('"
                            + Main_table
                            + "','"
                            + bill_no
                            + "','UNPAID',"
                            + Total
                            + ",'"
                            + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            + "','"
                            + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                            + "','"
                            + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "')");
            Log.d("Month", "" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            ArrayList<String> specialReq = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> quantityList = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> itemNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String tempItemId = null;
            Cursor cursor_order = db
                    .rawQuery(
                            "select item.Item_name, order_tbl.special_request,order_tbl.quantity from item, order_tbl where order_tbl.item_id=item.item_code",
                            null);
            cursor_order.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor_order != null) {
                do {

                    itemNameList.add(cursor_order.getString(0));
                    quantityList.add(cursor_order.getInt(2) + "");

                    specialReq.add(cursor_order.getString(1));
                } while (cursor_order.moveToNext());
                dbConnection.dataOutputStream.write(itemNameList.size());
                for (int l = 0; l < itemNameList.size(); l++) {
                    dbConnection.dataOutputStream.writeUTF(Main_table);
                    dbConnection.dataOutputStream.writeUTF(itemNameList.get(l));
                    dbConnection.dataOutputStream.writeUTF(specialReq.get(l));
                    dbConnection.dataOutputStream.writeUTF(quantityList.get(l));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("EDC", "" + e);
        }

        db.delete(table_name, col_name + " = '" + order_no + "'", null);

    }

    public void getFoodItems(String tableName) {

        food_items = db.rawQuery("select * from " + tableName, null);
        food_items.moveToFirst();
        image_details = getFavResults();
        if (food_items.getCount() != 0) {
            Log.d("count khali nahi h", "bilkl nai h");

            calculateOrder();

        }

    }

    public void calculateOrder() {
        Cursor order;

        Cursor customer_order;
        String bill_no;

        int count;
        Cursor favourite_cursor;

        try {
            DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection(getApplicationContext());
            db = dbcon.getConnection();
            food_items.moveToFirst();

            col_name = food_items.getColumnName(0);
            Log.d("----------------col_name", col_name);

            if (food_items != null) {
                food_items.moveToFirst();
                Log.d("----------------col_name", "" + food_items.getCount());
                order_no = food_items.getString(0);

                do {
                    order = db.rawQuery(
                            "select item_price,item_name from item where item_code='"
                                    + food_items.getString(1) + "'", null);
                    order.moveToFirst();
                    quantity = food_items.getInt(3);
                    Total += quantity * order.getInt(0);
                    Title_txt.setText("Total :" + Total);
                    Log.d("-------to", "" + Total);
                } while (food_items.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("dialog error", e.toString());
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> getFavResults() {
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

        try {
            if (food_items != null) {
                Log.d("order_tbl ID", "" + food_items.getString(1));
                do {
                    fav_item = db.rawQuery(
                            "select * from item where item_code='"
                                    + food_items.getString(1) + "'", null);
                    fav_item.moveToFirst();
                    item_id = fav_item.getString(1);
                    item_name = fav_item.getString(0);
                    item_descrp = fav_item.getString(2);
                    item_price = fav_item.getString(17);
                    ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
                    item_details.setName(item_name);
                    item_details.setItem_id(item_id);
                    item_details.setItemDescription(item_descrp);
                    item_details.setPrice(item_price);
                    item_details.setImage(fav_item.getBlob(10));
                    item_details.setcount(food_items.getInt(3));
                    results.add(item_details);
                } while (food_items.moveToNext());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Coooooool Errorrrrrrrrrrrr", e.toString());
        }
        db.close();
        return results;
    }





//-----and myOrderAdapter class----------------------------


public class MyOrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private static ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

    private Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.coffee, R.drawable.coffee,
            R.drawable.coffee, R.drawable.coffee, R.drawable.coffee,
            R.drawable.coffee };

    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    private Context context;

    private String table_name;

    public MyOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDetails> results,
            String table_name) {
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.table_name = table_name;

    }


    public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_myorder, parent,
                    false);

            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_titletag);

            holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_price);
            holder.txt_itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_quantity);
            holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_food_img);
            holder.plusBtn = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_plus_btn);
            holder.minusBtn = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_minus_btn);
            holder.removeBtn = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_remove_btn);
            holder.edittext = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myorder_edit_txt);

            holder.plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                private SQLiteDatabase db;
                private ItemDetails item_list;
                private ContentValues cv;
                int count = 1;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    item_list = itemDetailsrrayList.get((Integer) v.getTag());
                    count = item_list.getcount();
                    count++;

                    try {
                        DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection(context);
                        db = dbcon.getConnection();
                        cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("quantity", count);
                        db.update(table_name, cv,
                                "item_id='" + item_list.getItem_id() + "'",
                                null);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context
                                .getApplicationContext(), MyOrderList.class);
                        intent.putExtra("table_name", table_name);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Count", "" + e);
                    }

                }
            });

            holder.minusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                private SQLiteDatabase db;
                private ItemDetails item_list;
                private ContentValues cv;
                int count;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    item_list = itemDetailsrrayList.get((Integer) v.getTag());
                    count = item_list.getcount();

                    if (count > 1)
                        count--;
                    else
                        count = 1;

                    try {
                        DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection(context);
                        db = dbcon.getConnection();
                        cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("quantity", count);
                        db.update(table_name, cv,
                                "item_id='" + item_list.getItem_id() + "'",
                                null);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context
                                .getApplicationContext(), MyOrderList.class);
                        intent.putExtra("table_name", table_name);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Count", "" + e);
                    }

                }
            });

            holder.removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                private SQLiteDatabase db;

                private ItemDetails item_list;
                private ContentValues cv;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        item_list = itemDetailsrrayList.get((Integer) v
                                .getTag());

                        DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection(context);
                        db = dbcon.getConnection();

                        db.delete(table_name,
                                "item_id='" + item_list.getItem_id() + "'",
                                null);
                        db.close();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context
                                .getApplicationContext(), MyOrderList.class);
                        intent.putExtra("table_name", table_name);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("errorrrrrr", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_itemName
                .setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_itemQuantity.setText("Quantity");

        holder.txt_itemPrice.setText("Rs :"
                + itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position)
                .getImage());

        holder.edittext.setText(Integer.toString(itemDetailsrrayList.get(
                position).getcount()));

        holder.plusBtn.setTag(position);
        holder.minusBtn.setTag(position);

        holder.removeBtn.setText("Remove");
        holder.removeBtn.setTag(position);

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        public TextView edittext;
        public TextView txt_itemQuantity;
        public ImageButton minusBtn;
        public ImageButton plusBtn;
        public Button removeBtn;

        TextView txt_itemName;
        TextView txt_itemDescription;
        TextView txt_itemPrice;
        ImageView itemImage;

        public ViewHolder() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code that you have done

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i have my two activities myOrderList and MyOrderAdapter in  one have defined listview and in second activity i'm fiiling values in adapter....

Answer (score 0):

I have done that a few times defining my adapter in a separate class and refreshing it's data. Not sure if it's the right way, but at least it's working like a charm for me.

The thing which I am doing is that I clear all my ArrayList's which I am using to populate the list view, than add all the new items and set `adapter.notifySetDataChanged();` to my adapter.

Here is a sample :

if I populate my list view like this in onCreate for example :

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("one");
ids.add("two");
ids.add("three");

ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(ids);
lview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and for example if I want to update my listview on button click ar any other event I simply do this :

```
   ids.clear();
   ids.add("four");
   ids.add("five");
   ids.add("six");

   adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
```

and voala! : )

Comment: i appreciate ur effort but it still doesn't work for me....as u r clearing the aarylist object...but i dont want to clear it....i just want to update it....as u can see In my MyOrderAdapter class..i have plus and minus button click event where i'm updating values...i want it should reflect on my Listview.....i used myadapterObject.notifydataSetChanged()....plz do help me out..

Comment: did you try to add the new values in the arraylist and than use `notifySetDataChanged()` ?

Comment: no i have just changed or update the value already present in my adapter.......can  i notify my adapter without adding new values...

Comment: so let me check if i understand you correct : you are updating for example 25-th element of array list and than notify your adapter, right?

Comment: yes u r right...by the way i resolved this issue..:) thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to update a **listview** or a **gridview**
you have to **create a new adapter** with an updated array.

```
listView.setAdapter(new adapter());
listView.invalidateViews();
```